# Substantivo para "aficionado"?

Tags: português-brasileiro

Em português temos a palavra "aficionado" que se refere a alguém que tem uma paixão por algum tema, porém não encontro registros para uma palavra originária do adjetivo, como, por exemplo, "afição" ou algo do tipo.

Existe alguma palavra que aja como o substantivo para o adjetivo "aficionado"?

Comment: Acho que o termo mais comum para isso é fã.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O substantivo mais próximo seria **"afeição"**, do qual o adjetivo teve a sua origem através do Espanhol.   Aparentemente **"aficionado"** teve origem em **"affección"** (*"afeição"* em Espanhol) que, por sua vez, teve origem em **"affectio"** (*"afeto"* em Latim)

> - **aficionado**  –  do Espanhol aficionado, “devotado, fã, entusiasta”, de afección, “ato de ter gosto ou paixão por alguma coisa”.  E esta, por sua vez, vem do Latim affectio, “inclinação, influência, estado permanente de sentir”, de efficere, “fazer algo a alguém, agir sobre”.   [**Origem Da Palavra - Site de Etimologia**](http://origemdapalavra.com.br/site/palavras/aficionado/)

Comment: Em espanhol, as palavras são **afeción e afición**.

Answer (score 3):

Encontramos em português tanto o substantivo *afeição* quanto *afecção*, ambos oriundos do latim *affectio*.

Contudo, além de serem relativamente pouco usados no português brasileiro, penso que nenhum dos dois substantivos se presta como substantivação da ideia contida no adjetivo *aficionado*.

*Afeição* indica um carinho, um pendor, uma inclinação para alguma coisa ou alguém. Todavia, trata-se de um sentimento delicado, terno. O verbo *afeiçoar-se*, por sua vez, já é um pouco mais comum. Mas ambos têm semanticamente pouco a ver com o sentido de *aficionado*, estando muito mais próximos do adjetivo *afetuoso*.

O termo *afecção* não aparece na linguagem falada. É um termo técnico que na medicina se refere a uma alteração patológica do corpo ou, na psicologia, a uma morbidez ou anormalidade psíquica. Também é usado por alguns autores da filosofia moderna. Mas, de qualquer forma, não é um termo da linguagem cotidiana.

Penso que o substantivo que melhor transmite a ideia relativa ao sentimento pelo qual alguém *aficionado* encontra-se tomado seja *paixão* (*por*). Além disso, em um registro um pouco mais informal, *loucura* (*por*) também pode ser usado.

Um aficionado por charutos, por exemplo, é alguém que tem uma *paixão*, ou uma *loucura* **por** charutos.

Answer (score 0):

As palavras mais óbvias seriam amante ou amador.

AULETE: [Brasil]
(a.ma.dor) [ô]
a.
1. Que pratica uma atividade por prazer e não por profissão; DILETANTE [P.opos. a profissional.]
2. Que gosta muito de alguma coisa ou pessoa; AMANTE; APRECIADOR
3. Pej. Que é inexperiente em algum assunto ou atividade
4. Diz-se da atividade praticada por amadores (1) (esporte amador)

PRIBERAM:
a·ma·dor |ô| 
(amar + -dor)
adjectivo e substantivo masculino
1. Que ou o que ama; que ou o que gosta muito de algo ou de alguém. = AMANTE, APRECIADOR
2. Que ou aquele que, por gosto e não por profissão, exerce qualquer ofício ou arte.
3. Que ou o que revela inexperiência em algum assunto ou actividade.
adjectivo
4. Que é praticado ou exercido por gosto e não profissionalmente (ex.: desporto amador; teatro amador).

"amador", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/amador [consultado em 22-10-2016].